# On Debian, running mono- error CS8027: Error running pkg-config

Tags: c#, linux, mono, debian, pkg-config

I am on debian.
I did sudo apt-get install mono-complete

I am trying to compile this program

```
user@debian:~$ cat a2.cs
using Gtk;
using System;

class Hello {

        static void Main()
        {
                Application.Init ();

                Window window = new Window ("helloworld");
                window.Show();

                Application.Run ();

        }
}
```

Then when I try to compile it I get this error

```
user@debian:~$ mcs a2.cs -pkg:gtk-sharp-2.0
Package gtk-sharp-2.0 was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `gtk-sharp-2.0.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'gtk-sharp-2.0' found
error CS8027: Error running pkg-config. Check the above output.
user@debian:~$
```

one answer to a similar problem said try dmcs

```
user@debian:~$ dmcs a2.cs -pkg:gtk-sharp-2.0
Package gtk-sharp-2.0 was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `gtk-sharp-2.0.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'gtk-sharp-2.0' found
error CS8027: Error running pkg-config. Check the above output.
user@debian:~$
```

but dmcs gives the same error

I saw a suggestion to do yum install gtk-sharp2 but whatever incantation I use it says no package available so i'm not sure what that package is

```
user@debian:~$ sudo yum install gtk-sharp-2.0
Setting up Install Process
No package gtk-sharp-2.0 available.
Nothing to do
user@debian:~$ 

user@debian:~$ sudo yum install gtk-sharp2-devel
Setting up Install Process
No package gtk-sharp2-devel available.
Nothing to do
user@debian:~$
```

I looked up my error  https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=cs8027   and they all say this variable PKG_CONFIG_PATH  has to point to the correct path.

At the moment though the variable doesn't exist and I don't know what path to point it to. Apparently it's a path with some .pc files for gtk. I have no idea where that is.

```
user@debian:/usr$ echo $PKG_CONFIG_PATH

user@debian:/usr$
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to map pkg-config names to yum/apt-get](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18475961/how-to-map-pkg-config-names-to-yum-apt-get)

Comment: yum in debian? no, I think you want to use apt-get; anyway I marked this question as a duplicate

Comment: @knocte The question you linked to has answers about Yum. The attempt at Yum (I understand one shouldn't in debian), running Yum was just a mistake and fortunately it didn't do anything.  I don't see any answer at your 'duplicate' link that solves my problem

Comment: there are 2 answers in the linked question, one talks about yum and the other about apt-get

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You say you are using debian, yet you run `yum`?
Doesn't seem like a good idea.

Try running:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install gtk-sharp2
```

Then, don't forget to do:

```
make clean
```

And start the compilation process from the very beginning.

**added by barlop**

I got errors the first time I tried it  like `problem: 0:System.Drawing.SizeF.Conversion, with xpath: /Type/Members/Member[@MemberName='op_Conversion']/Docs`  and I interrupted the installation but it continued trying to install then said it interrupted.

but doing that command again, apt-get didn't seem to install it again but immediately said it's the newest version, and my program compiled. So it must have installed or installed sufficiently despite the problems while installing.

it makes this file `/usr/lib/pkgconfig/gtk-sharp-2.0.pc` among others,

and

`$ dmcs a2.cs -pkg:gtk-sharp-2.0` <-- then works

Comment: I didn't compile it I just did an apt-get rather than compile. The only time I tried yum(I understand now that it was wrong to try yum in debian) but the only time I tried yum was as mentioned above, and fortunately it didn't do anything. So this doesn't solve the problem. Nevertheless, i'm running apt-get update and make clean now

Comment: So, `sudo apt-get gtk-sharp2-devel` didn't install the package?

Comment: there is no gtk-sharp2-devel  There is gtk-sharp2,  gtk-sharp2-examples, and gtp-sharp2-gapi   If I recall when I did gtk-sharp2 I got errors but i'll try it again and edit the result into my question if it fails

Comment: gtk-sharp2 is just a virtual package... by responding like this you're giving a fish to a hungry man instead of teaching him to fish, like we would do if he read the second answer of this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18475961/how-to-map-pkg-config-names-to-yum-apt-get

Comment: In this case, I think that link wouldn't be the relevant one. He was trying to fish with a baseball bat (yum in debian) and making his life more difficult. I don't think that teaching him how to add a string and bait to the baseball bat would have been the right call. I just told him to use a real fishing rod (apt-get in debian). Then, he got unstuck and found a different error and he himself fixed it (great for him!); also, I think he'll keep using apt-get in debian, until he has the need (and/or the will) to learn how to fish with a baseball bat. I think it's a good outcome.

Comment: @knocte you make a good point and it's worth it for a hungry man to accept the fish but still learn to fish. I just tried apt-file and it peaked my curiosity as to what files a package installs, so I tried.  `dpkg-query -L gtk-sharp2`  and it didn't show me that `.pc` file(which I know was crucial and got installed). Whereas  when I did that on the proper package, the package shown by apt-file, `dpkg-query -L libgtk2.0-cil-dev`   it showed me the .pc file. But i'm sure the gtk-sharp2 package installed the .pc file. How would I determine that it did?

Comment: I always use the Debian "package search": https://packages.debian.org/unstable/cli-mono/gtk-sharp2 Look the dependencies

Comment: @MikelPascual ah I see, from that site I see the the package(gtk-sharp2) itself doesn't have the .pc file in its file list, but it's dependent on that package that does(libgtk2.0-cil-dev). (and installing it would install the dependency thus install the .pc file).

Comment: you didn't apply the answer correctly, you should look carefully at barlop's question: you looked for `gtk-sharp2` with apt-file, but you should have looked for `gtk-sharp-2.0`

Comment: I looked at `No package 'gtk-sharp-2.0' found`. You are right, looking at `Perhaps you should add the directory containing 'gtk-sharp-2.0.pc'` would have been quite more precise.

Comment: directory? I guess you mean package

Comment: seriously guys, go to sleep and come back tomorrow

Comment: @knocte it's not clear who u r referring to when u say "you didn't apply the answer correctly".And when u refer to my question,I guess you mean the one in comment.Mikel didn't use apt-file at all, and when I used apt-file I (as per your valuable method) did `$ apt-file search --package-only gtk-sharp-2.0.pc` and got `libgtk2.0-cil-dev`.  The gtk-sharp-2.0.pc file goes into a directory that pkg-config checks for but if it hadn't,then as the error message suggests,(and as I think mikel meant)apparently it's possible to add a directory containing the pc file,to the env variable `PKG_CONFIG_PATH`

Comment: @MikelPascual  `user@debian:~$ pkg-config --variable pc_path pkg-config` shows the directories that pkg-config checks, and they include `/usr/lib/pkgconfig` which (after installing the gtksharp2 package via apt-get) has `/usr/lib/pkgconfig/gtk-sharp-2.0.pc`   Even if it hadn't(and i'd have had to add a directory with that pc file, to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH variable), then i'd still have had to install a [apt-get] package(gtk-sharp2)or perhaps just libgtk2.0-cil-dev would've sufficed but i'd still have to do that to put that file there 'cos it wasn't there or anywhere on my computer before(afaik).

Comment: @MikelPascual I have used configure and make before, and i've used apt-get many times. I simply read about using yum to solve that error and didn't realise that that doesn't apply to Debian.  Also, the 'make clean' in your answer doesn't do anything in this case, it says "no rule to make target clean".

Comment: why do you ask for doing a `make clean`?

Comment: @jgomo3 That is the way to make sure the system compiles everything again

Comment: @MikelPascual but I didn't see it related with mcs. Is it?